# 1-out-of-2 Oblivious Transfer Security

Tags: rsa, security-definition, oblivious-transfer, rabin-cryptosystem

Just started reading Oblivious Transfer. I am searching for a proof of security based on RSA implementation but I can't find anything simple to understand. Can someone direct/show me to an easy to understand proof of it's security?

Many thanks

Comment: You might want to list the protocol that uses RSA to perform OT

Comment: Hi Poncho! I'm looking at Coin flipping protocol and Contract signing protocol by EGL. I don't fully understand how to show that it's secure both for sender and receiver. Many thanks